# Remove predicate from nested structure (google guava predicates)

Tags: java, guava, predicate

I use google guava predicates and I want to filter it to be able to remove some of them.

For example in this code

```
Predicates.or(
    Predicates.and(p1, p2, Predicates.or(p3, p4)),
    Predicates.and(p3, p2, Predicates.or(p1, p4))
    Predicates.and(p3, p2, Predicates.or(Predicates.and(p1, p2), Predicates.and(p2, p3)))
);
```

I want to remove `p1` so the result should look like this

```
Predicates.or(
    Predicates.and(p2, Predicates.or(p3, p4)),
    Predicates.and(p3, p2, Predicates.or(p4))
    Predicates.and(p3, p2, Predicates.or(Predicates.and(p2), Predicates.and(p2, p3)))
);
```

Is it possible? If yes, how?

Why? We reuse some of predicates with exceptions.

Comment: What do you mean with `remove`? You want to re-factor the code, so that `p1` is not used and the code compiles fine?

Comment: `Predicates` is some kind of a list and I want to remove item from the list (nested list as you see in the example).

Comment: `Predicates` is a *builder* which holds some instructions. It's not 100% sure that internally it's a list and even it is, this list is not exposed to the public, which means it's not meant to be directly accessed and changed.

Comment: You may be right but my question is - is it possible to remove predicate from this builder/list?

Comment: No, I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

Not after the fact - the `Predicate` returned from `Predicates.and()` and `Predicates.or()` is a black-box, and (by design) provides no way to inspect its component parts.

The right solution is to refactor your code so that you compose this predicate with only the component predicates you intend. One option would be to replace `p1` with a `alwaysTrue()` or `alwaysFalse()` predicate, like so:

```
Predicate<T> p1OrTrue = p1;
Predicate<T> p1OrFalse = p1;
if (dontUseP1) {
  p1OrTrue = Prediactes.alwaysTrue();
  p1OrFalse = Predicates.alwaysFalse();
}

Predicates.or(
    Predicates.and(p1OrTrue, p2, Predicates.or(p3, p4)),
    Predicates.and(p3, p2, Predicates.or(p1OrFalse, p4))
    Predicates.and(p3, p2, Predicates.or(Predicates.and(p1OrTrue, p2), Predicates.and(p2, p3)))
);
```

This means if `dontUseP1` is `false` then `p1` will be incorporated in the composite predicate as before, but if it's `true` it will instead be replaced with no-op predicates that cause `Predicates.or()` (`alwaysFalse()`) and `Predicates.and()` (`alwaysTrue()`) to rely on the result of the remaining component predicates, making the predicate equivalent to not having `p1` at all.